# Mongodb: The paging file is too small ... v2.6.4 on Win2012

Tags: mongodb

We had this a couple weeks ago, and mongo would not restart.
We have 30GB RAM. The paging file had originally ben 4gb. When we first hit this a couple weeks ago, we incrased the paging file to 12GB min/25GB max.

Then a few days ago.... the server terminated again:

```
2014-10-01T00:24:05.664-0500 [conn3421] insert dotnetwrapper_mongodb.LogItem ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:1814629 1818ms
2014-10-01T00:24:05.914-0500 [conn3419] VirtualProtect for c:/MongoDB/Data/dotnetwrapper_mongodb/dotnetwrapper_mongodb.309 chunk 46821 failed with errno:1455 The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (chunk size is 67108864, address is 2db94000000) in mongo::makeChunkWritable, terminating
2014-10-01T00:24:05.914-0500 [conn3419] dotnetwrapper_mongodb.LogItem Fatal Assertion 16362
2014-10-01T00:24:08.082-0500 [conn3419] mongod.exe    ???
```

Fortunately, it came back up OK.

Aside from the obvious (don't use mongo for production systems! -- this is a logging system)...

What do we need to do to solve this forever?
(A 50GB paging file seems not appro...)

Comment: Looks like you found https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10044 - did you try doubling page file size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the answer is in the mongo jira system:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10044

- The know the problem
- It has affected many users
- At this writing, they are working on a resolution

As of March 2015, the bug is still open, and our mongo server goes down every month or two.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue (see also https://serverfault.com/a/637052/239616) with the old MMAPv1 storage engine in older versions. MongoDB decided not to fix it and instead refer to their production notes:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#production-windows-pagefile

However, a better solution would most likely be to upgrade to a newer version of MongoDB and use the WiredTiger storage engine (or whatever the current replacement to MMAPv1 is). This should eliminate the problem (while potentially introducing a whole lot of new ones).

Comment: Thanks!  We ripped out Mongodb years ago. We replaced it with an elasticsearch-based system that we built that works great and has been in production for a couple of years now. Mongodb failed us and will never be reconsidered.